# Text flows around div with 'position: absolute'

Tags: html, css

I have two overlapping divs: content and its header. Example is simplified:

```css
 .a {
   background-color: red;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
 }
 .b {
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">HEADER</div>
  CONTENT
  <br />CONTENT
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mk6y1tbw/

Is it possible to do somehow that CONTENT will flow under `b` div and will not be hided by 'b` div?

P.S. Div are provided by third-party as is and I am unable to rearrange their order or position in HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

Question if you really need `position: absolute` on the `b` div. Can't you achieve the same result by using normal positioning. By adding some negative margin to the `b` class you can negate the effect of the padding on the `a` class? Using normal positioning has the advantage that you don't have to think about the height of the content in the `<div>` with class `b`.

For example:

```css
.a {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: -10px -10px 0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">HEADER</div>
  CONTENT
  <br />CONTENT
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 10px `margin-top` to first div and subtract it from another as follows:

```css
    .a {
        background-color: red; 
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    .b {
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;
        margin-top:-10px; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">HEADER</div>
    CONTENT<br />CONTENT
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding of `.a` doesn't provide space for `.b`. Apply extra `padding-top` to `.a`:

```
.a { background-color: red; padding: 10px; padding-top:28px; position: relative; }
.b { background-color: blue; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mk6y1tbw/1/

`28px` is the height (renders as `18px` in Chrome -- be sure to specify a `height` for `.b`) + the `10px` default padding.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution. First thing I thought about were margins :D

Comment: @nicael - In my opinion it isn't the best solution if `.b`'s `height` is unknown.

Comment: However, are you sure that every browser will render the content of the `<div>` with class `b` using exactly the same height?

Comment: @ckui but you can just specify height explicitly, whats wrong with it?.. Btw, in my browser it renders correctly.

Comment: @ckuijjer Yes, `.b` should have height specified.